# Use custom url for HtmlService webapp

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

Is there a way to use a specific cname to run a Htmlservice webapp ?
I would like to user something like app.domain.com to run the htmlservice app.

I see that this works inside a Google Site but the Google site doesn't manage correctly the  tags

Comment: What tags doesn't it manage correctly?

Comment: For example, when defining a fixed position of a <div>, because the Google Site uses a frame to include the webapp, this fixed position has no effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible. At most you can use your custom url and program it to redirect to your apps script webapp. That way its easy to type and remember.

Answer (score 3):

The solution posted by @Karl_S works with the published /exec urls but not with the /dev ones. Furthermore the responsive design is lost because the frame redirect skips the viewport setting in the html wrapper. An alternative would be to host the wrapping html page on your domain and add the viewport setting in the head while keeping the rest what the frame redirect does. For example the following worked for me:

```
<html><head>
  <title>My App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <frameset rows="100%">
  <frame src="https://script.google.com/a/.../exec" 
         title="My App" 
         frameborder="0" 
         noresize="noresize">
  </frameset>
</html>
```

Also make sure to publish your script with cross domain restriction disabled, i.e. In your script ensure you call

```
HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(...)
  .evaluate()
  .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I have published web apps working via a Forwarded subdomain with masking.  The URL does not change and client side interaction works and is posted back to my files as well.  So instead of https://script.google.com/a/bondwood.net/d/1y3iLTLT....  I have mysubdomain.bondwood.net  If I want to pass parameters I do have to throw a dummy character is, so  mysubdomain.bondwood.net/n?arg1=xyz&arg3=abc

Note that currently any responsive design is being lost via the subdomain but is working via the raw url. This is the only thing I have found to not work at this time.

Answer (score 0):

A CNAME record is an abbreviation for Canonical Name record and is a type of resource record in the Domain Name System (DNS) used to specify that a **domain name** is an alias for another domain, the "canonical" domain. All information, including subdomains, IP addresses, etc, are defined by the canonical domain. [CNAME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record)

But the HTML service lets you serve **web pages** that can interact with server-side Apps Script functions. [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

It's a dubious advantage for public pages (not for internal apps).

If you really want to have Google Apps Script Server you need publish a page on a web-server and interact by REST.

Yes, you'll lost [Client-side API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host). Do you really need it?

For an example you can publish a GihHib page [Setting up a custom domain with GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/)

Look at [my simple app](http://www.googledrive.com/host/0Bztea6vSatozfmU3em9wSU9wTDRTQV9LUXBCNmpyZWhOcjhNWlUyOHc0WjBVdzF6ZWlmU2s) which deploeded on [Google Drive Host](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en)

Cheers!

Comment: You lose a lot more than client side api.

Comment: @ZigMandel Yes, like Autentification, User Properties.

Comment: Not just that. You lose everything. There ia no point in doing what you suggest with an apps acript.